# how i can use toggle and function that remove the class from the previous element together only using JavaScript i have tried to Different ways?

Tags: javascript

-*****First Way*****-

Here I Can't Remove The Previous Elements and add the class for The new One

```js
linksBtnArr.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", () => {
    arrowArr[index].classList.toggle("active");
    if (arrowArr[index].classList.contains("active")) {
      menuArr[index].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      menuArr[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

-*****Second Way*****-

Here I Can remove The previous Element But i Can't use Toggle to Remove The class Form The Same Element That i clicked again

```js
linksBtnArr.forEach((link, i) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", () => {
    removeActiveClasses();
    arrowArr[i].classList.add("active");
  });
});
// Remove The previous Menu
function removeActiveClasses() {
  arrowArr.forEach((arrow) => {
    arrow.classList.remove("active");
  });
}
```

Comment: neither, and you should probably use event delegation. But I will see more clearly if you also show the HTML part concerned (to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way

```js
linksBtnArr.forEach( (lk,_,All_lk) => {
  lk.onclick =_=> {
    if (lk.classList.toggle('active'))
      All_lk.forEach( lx=> lx.classList.toggle('active', lk===lx) )
  } })
```

Answer (score 0):

Look At The UL Links That what i'm trying to Do !
https://mohmostafa-web.github.io/blogr-landing-page-frontend-mentor

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Here's a [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) you might find useful...